# Make a objective C method that uses a swift protocol as parameter public accesable

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, methods, bridging-header

I have an objective-c method that uses a swift protocol as a parameter type. The signature looks like `+ (void) my_ObjC_method: (id<my_Swift_protocol>) parameter_name;`

I generally know how to make swift protocols accessible to objective C.
I implemented it this way:

```
@objC protocol my_Swift_protocol : class {
    //...methods go here
}
```

My problem is that I want to make `my_ObjC_method` public accessible. That would normally be done by simply adding it to the header file in the `@interface` part. Sadly, this requires to import the bridging header to the .h file, so that the .h file knows my swift protocol and recognizes it as a valid type. But you can't import the automatically generated bridging header into other header files.

What would be a good approach to solve or work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `@protocol` directive as a forward declaration.

MyClass.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol my_Swift_protocol;

@interface MyClass : NSObject
+ (void) my_ObjC_method: (id<my_Swift_protocol>) parameter_name;

@end
```